# Magento can't create product

Tags: magento, product

In magento I created simple product with this code:

```
try {
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product
    ->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) //website ID the product is assigned to, as an array
    ->setAttributeSetId(9) //ID of a attribute set named 'default'
    ->setTypeId('simple') //product type
    ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product creation time
    ->setSku('testsku17') //SKU
    ->setName('test product17') //product name
    ->setWeight(8.00)
    ->setStatus(1) //product status (1 - enabled, 2 - disabled)
    ->setTaxClassId(4) //tax class (0 - none, 1 - default, 2 - taxable, 4 - shipping)
    ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH) //catalog and search visibility
    ->setManufacturer(28) //manufacturer id
    ->setColor(24)
    ->setNewsFromDate(strtotime('now')) //product set as new from
    ->setNewsToDate('06/30/2015') //product set as new to
    ->setCountryOfManufacture('AF') //country of manufacture (2-letter country code)
    ->setPrice(11.22) //price in form 11.22
    ->setCost(22.33) //price in form 11.22
    ->setSpecialPrice(3.44) //special price in form 11.22
    ->setSpecialFromDate(strtotime('now')) //special price from (MM-DD-YYYY)
    ->setSpecialToDate('06/30/2015') //special price to (MM-DD-YYYY)
    ->setMsrpEnabled(1) //enable MAP
    ->setMsrpDisplayActualPriceType(1) //display actual price (1 - on gesture, 2 - in cart, 3 - before order confirmation, 4 - use config)
    ->setMsrp(99.99) //Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price
    ->setMetaTitle('test meta title')
    ->setMetaKeyword('testproduct')
    ->setMetaDescription('test meta description')
    ->setDescription('This is a long description')
    ->setShortDescription('This is a short description')
    ->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ())) //media gallery initialization
    ->setStockData(array(
                       'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
                       'manage_stock'=>1, //manage stock
                       'min_sale_qty'=>1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                       'max_sale_qty'=>2, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                       'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
                       'qty' => 999 //qty
                   )
    )
    ->setCategoryIds(array(3, 10)); //assign product to categories
$product->save();
}catch(Exception $e){
Mage::log($e->getMessage());
}
```

First time it was succesful created product, but it was displayed only in sql.
If I tried create another product, its nothing happend.
Now I delete products and try to create again, but nothing happens.

Hope your help!

Comment: I tried, but not help.

Comment: Hi, i get other code now, which working. Now i have a problem, because the product is displayed only in database and not in magento admin.

Answer (score 0):

my code is:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
                $product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
                $product->setTypeId('simple');
                $product->setName('TESTTEST');
                $product->setDescription('TESTPRODUKT');
                $product->setShortDescription('&nbsp;');
                $product->setStatus(1);
                $product->setTaxClassId(1);
                $product->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH); //catalog and search visibility
                $product->setWeight(0);
                $product->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'));
                $product->setManufacturer(1);
                $product->setAttributeSetId(2);
                $product->setSku('SKUTEST222');
                $product->setPrice(5);
                $product->setVisibility(1);
                $product->save();
```

Comment: please can anybody help me?